# Call variadic function in C++ with array as arguments

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

Suppose I have a simple variadic function like this:

```
template <typename... A>
void func(A... args)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

And I need another function to call the arguments from an array, let's say:

```
int arg[3] = {1,2,3};
```

call the function

```
func(1,2,3);
```

Is it possible to do this without modifying the templated function?

Comment: maybe you could write a (also templated) wrapper function which applies the arguments to the original

Comment: try that - [Passing std::array as arguments of template variadic function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16834851/passing-stdarray-as-arguments-of-template-variadic-function)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could write `apply` which takes a reference to an array and functor to call with the unpacked array (you might want to add perfect forwarding and such):

```
template <typename F, typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t... Idx>
decltype(auto) apply_impl (F f, T (&t)[N], std::index_sequence<Idx...>) {
    return f(t[Idx]...);
}

template <typename F, typename T, std::size_t N>
decltype(auto) apply (F f, T (&t)[N]) {
    return apply_impl(f, t, std::make_index_sequence<N>{});   
}
```

Then call it like this, if `foo` is a functor class:

```
apply(foo{}, a);
```

If `foo` is just a normal template function like in your example, you could wrap it in a lambda:

```
apply([](auto...xs){foo(std::forward<decltype(xs)>(xs)...);}, a);
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9c9b03077827663b)

Comment: What if I want to pass multiple types to that template, for instance, I want to call foo("a", 1, 3.0). Do you have any hints on how to do that?

Comment: Use a `std::tuple` and the same kind of approach, substituting `t[Idx]` for `std::get<Idx>(t)` and array references for the tuple.

Comment: But I also don't know a priori what kind of elements I'm getting, can be `foo("a")` or `foo(1,2.0)`. Otherwise I end up in the same problem while specifying the `std::tuple` So what I have is just a list of pairs for example, so that the second value specifies the type, can this still be done?!

Comment: @Fynn I'm not sure I understand. I'd recommend making another question which details your issue.