# fixed size container to variadic template argument list conversion

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I have to call a variadic template function which can take any number of arguments.

```
template < class ... Args >
void f( Args&... args);
```

I wish to write a small wrapper function so that I can call `f` with N arguments of the same type contained in a fixed size container like std::array.

The goal is to write something like

```
std::array<int, 3> arr = {1,2,3};
wrapper(arr); // calls f(1,2,3);
```

I tried to use some combination of initializer lists and `std::forward` but to no avail. Is there a way to achieve what I want ?

Comment: I think you might be looking for a [`std::integer_sequence`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence)

Comment: @NathanOliver -- what if the type of the arguments may be something other than `int` ?

Comment: I see two problem for making it generic: Creating a tuple from your container, and unpacking the tuple into the argument pack. The latter part [have already been done](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1547118/440558) which leaves the creation of the tuple which I unfortunately have no idea how to do.

Comment: @Louen As Joachim Pileborg said I think then you need a tuple but I do not know how you would construct it.

Comment: @Louen you can use [make_tuple](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/make_tuple)

Comment: If it can work with a tuple, why not with any compile-time sized container ?

Comment: You need to have a parameter pack.  I don't think you can convert an array to a parameter pack.

Comment: I think you could go from a non-type parameter pack to an initializer list, to a std::array, so long as it was okay to construct the array from the parameter pack instead of the other way around.

Comment: @NathanOliver It's as easy as converting a tuple to a parameter pack since `std::array` has the same interface (`std::get`, `std::tuple_size`, etc.).

Comment: @cpplearner Good to know.  Some of these TMP techniques are still obscure to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve it using `std::array` , inspired by the tuple solution in [How do I expand a tuple into variadic template function's arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687490/how-do-i-expand-a-tuple-into-variadic-template-functions-arguments/1547118#1547118)

(Edited : std::array version, first version used raw pointers)

```
// Function I want to call : 
template< class... Args >
void f( Args&... args ) {
    // ...
}
```

Using recursive templates who grab the arguments *from the end of the array* (so that they end up in the correct order).
A specialization at `I = 0` has all the arguments in the `Args..args` and  calls `f()`

```
namespace Helper {
template< unsigned int N, unsigned int I > 
struct Caller {
    template< class T, class...Args >
    static void call( const std::array<T,N>& arr, Args&... args  ){
        Caller<N,I-1>::call( arr, std::get<I-1>(arr), args... );
    }
};

template < unsigned int N >
struct Caller<N, 0> {
    template< class T, class...Args >
    static void call( const std::array<T,N>&  arr, Args&... args ) {
        f(args...);
    }
};
}
```

Let's wrap it up in a nice function

```
template< typename T, unsigned N >
void call_f( const std::array<T,N>& arr ){
    Helper::Caller<N,N>::call(arr);
}
```

Here's what the calling code looks like.

```
std::array<float,3> array = {4.3, 3.14,2.1} ;
call_f(array);
```

[Live version here](http://ideone.com/a26Sqs)

Answer (score 8):

If your compiler supports C++14 you can do it the following way:

```
template <class ... Args>
void f(Args&&... args) {
...
}

template<typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t... I>
void wrapper_impl(std::array<T, N> const &arr, std::index_sequence<I...>) {
  f(arr[I]...);
}

template<typename T, std::size_t N, 
         typename Indices = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
void wrapper(std::array<T, N> const &arr) {
  wrapper_impl(arr, Indices());
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/77aa901fc3d216db)

For C++11 based on this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16834851/passing-stdarray-as-arguments-of-template-variadic-function) you could code some extra machinery and do it as below (haven't test it though):

```
namespace detail {
  template<std::size_t... Is>        struct seq {};
  template<std::size_t N, int... Is> struct gen_seq : gen_seq<N-1,N-1, Is...> {};
  template<std::size_t... Is>        struct gen_seq<0, Is...> : seq<Is...> {};
}

template <class ... Args>
void f(Args&&... args) {
...
}

template<typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t... I>
void wrapper_impl(std::array<T, N> const &arr, detail::seq<I...>) {
  f(arr[I]...);
}

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
void wrapper(std::array<T, N> const &arr) {
  wrapper_impl(arr, detail::gen_seq<N>());
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7c07ffe7c9812bc1)