# How to write an overload function for std::array that calls a variadic function?

Tags: c++, arrays, lambda, variadic

I have the following variadic function:

```
template <typename... Args>
CustomType<Args...> method(const Args& args...);
```

which works fine when I just do e.g.

```
method(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f);
```

However I also want to write an overload for `std::array<T, N>`:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
auto method(const std::array<T, N>& arr);
```

Reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35232057/fixed-size-container-to-variadic-template-argument-list-conversion) I figured I would use the following helper functions:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N, typename VariadicFunc, uint32_t... I>
auto methodApply(const std::array<T, N>& arr, VariadicFunc func, std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
    return func(arr[I]...);
}

template <typename T, std::size_t N, typename VariadicFunc, typename Indices = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
auto methodArr(const std::array<T, N>& arr, VariadicFunc func)
{
    return methodApply(arr, func, Indices());
}
```

and then do

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
auto method(const std::array<T, N>& arr)
{
   methodArr(arr, /* what to pass here? */);
}
```

Note: the reason why I would like to template on `func` is because I want these helper functions to be generic so that I may use them for other variadic functions, not just `method()`.

Only I'm not sure what pass as the second argument - I was thinking of a lambda function that would make a call to the original function `method(const Args& args...)` but it's unclear to me how to do this.

EDIT:
Restricted to C++14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap it in a lambda and let the compiler deduce the type for you

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
auto method(const std::array<T, N>& arr)
{
   return methodArr(arr, [](const auto&... args) { return method(args...); });
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9T8e66KT9)

In C++17, `methodApply` can be replaced with [`std::apply`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply)

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
auto method(const std::array<T, N>& arr) {
  return std::apply(
    [](const auto&... args) { return method(args...); }, arr);
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm restricted to C++14.